# IMACROS on QUOKA.DE \ Dynamic IDs in ajax text forms

Tags: automation, scripting, imacros

I'm trying to automate some messages on this website ( you have to register to use it ): https://www.quoka.de/partnerschaften-kontakte/freundschaft-unternehmungen/

After clicking on "CONTACT USER", a floating modal form open:

The problem is that every form have a dynamic ID, and seems very complicated to identify each one on page refresh.
I've tried with **relative positioning** after clicking on the form TITLE, but sometimes works, sometimes not. why ???

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=H4 ATTR=TXT:Kontaktieren
TAG POS=R2 TYPE=TEXTAREA FORM=NAME:MailForm ATTR=CLASS:*qx_form* CONTENT=MESSAGE
TAG POS=R3 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:MailForm ATTR=CLASS:*qx_form* CONTENT=NAME
```

HTML code extracted from the form is:

```
<textarea name="d27c24cfcee6f7a903493b06461ab4df" id="d27c24cfcee6f7a903493b06461ab4df" placeholder="Deine Nachricht" rows="5" class="qx_form__textarea qx_contact-form__textarea c-920fd75ddc014107b4496d8b28c1189f" cols="80" wrap="virtual"></textarea>
```

This is the one for the NAME field:

```
<input name="f59e9b8df721b5ea5b273cc7620f984a" id="f59e9b8df721b5ea5b273cc7620f984a" value="" class="qx_form__input qx_contact-form__input c-8e5f605b4cd88fb0219f9e560862671f qx_form__input_first" placeholder="Dein Name" style="border-top-right-radius: 3px ! important; border-top-left-radius: 3px ! important;" type="text">
```

Is there a simple solution maybe using "placeholders" or a well calibrated relative positioning ?
Thanks.

---

Windows 7 PRO (64 bit) \ Waterfox 51.0.1 (64 bit) \ iMacros for FF free 8.9.7

Comment: Maybe an "Idea" to mention your FCI (sorry, tired about asking) + your parallel Thread on the iMacros Forum...: https://forum.imacros.net/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=30497 - + Screenshots on 'imgur' are completely Legit on this Forum... - (And watch out about the [javascript] Tag, you may want to remove it, or your Thread might end up "closed as off-topic" by the 'javascript' Gurus/Watchers...

Comment: )              [ <= Closing Braket... ] (As typos can't be corrected after 5min, even if the 'edit' Link/button remains buggily active for 20min...)

Comment: "Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes" [x]

Comment: Yep, 'Edit' Button for my previous Comment still present at "21 mins ago" but disappeared after a 'Refresh'... - Sorry @ OP, but Site is so ridiculously buggy that nearly every Click anywhere unveils stg "funny" and "unexpected" to investigate, ah-ah...! - But OK, I didn't really had anything to add to your Thread here, I prefer the iMacros Forum anyway... - Just like there is no Formatting in Comments, can't even add a Soft/Hard-Return, ah-ah...!!

Hum, 'Shift-Enter' did stg though..., this might be new...
 Nope, another buggy "Joke", ah-ah...! (Formatting remains though in 'Edit' Mode...)

Answer (score 0):

```
function InputMessage(msg)
{
    var ele=window.content.document.querySelectorAll("textarea[placeholder='Deine Nachricht']");
    for(var i=1;i<=ele.length;i++)
        iimPlayCode("SET !ERRORIGNORE YES\nSET !TIMEOUT_STEP 0\nTAG POS="+i+" TYPE=TEXTAREA ATTR=placeholder:Deine<SP>Nachricht CONTENT="+msg.replace(/ /g,"<SP>"));
}

function InputName(name)
{
    var ele=window.content.document.querySelectorAll("input[placeholder='Dein Name']");
    for(var i=1;i<=ele.length;i++)
        iimPlayCode("SET !ERRORIGNORE YES\nSET !TIMEOUT_STEP 0\nTAG POS="+i+" TYPE=INPUT ATTR=placeholder:Dein<SP>Name CONTENT="+name.replace(/ /g,"<SP>"));
}
```

Solution found in this iMacros thread "[Loop and dynamic ID form compiler](https://forum.imacros.net/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=30506&p=83460#p83460)".